# Why is my Interceptor not working?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

I have two different projects: A and B.

B contains one Interceptor that I'd like to use in project A and, in the future, projects C and D.

I'm using jboss-javaee-6.0 version 3.0.3.Final in both projects (this means, CDI version 1.0).

Project B (does not contain beans.xml):

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PerformanceLog {
}

@Interceptor
@PerformanceLog
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingInterceptor.class);

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Entered method (" + ctx.getMethod().getName() + ") of class (" + ctx.getMethod().getClass() + ").");
    }
}
```

Project A (contains beans.xml):

beans.xml (declares Interceptor in order to activate it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

<interceptors>
    <class>commons.utils.logging.performanceInterceptor.LoggingInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

MyControllerC:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyControllerC implements Serializable {
     ... 

    @PerformanceLog
    public void init() {
       //do some BD access here
    }
}
```

When I deploy the application I get the error

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001417 Enabled interceptor class <class>commons.utils.logging.performanceInterceptor.LoggingInterceptor    </class> in file:/D:/projectos/myProject/target/myProject/WEB-INF/beans.xml@7 is neither annotated @Interceptor nor registered through a portable extension:org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001417 Enabled interceptor class <class>commons.utils.logging.performanceInterceptor.LoggingInterceptor</class> in file:/D:/projectos/myProject/target/myProject/WEB-INF/beans.xml@7 is neither annotated @Interceptor nor registered through a portable extension
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateEnabledInterceptorClasses(Validator.java:503)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:373)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:110)
at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:76)
```

My first tought was that because the Interceptor is inside a jar that's in project A lib, it was not visible. I upgraded to java-ee 7 version 1.0.3.Final and CDI 1.1 so that I could use the tag @Priority in LoggingInterceptor. The error disappeared, however it did not work (nothing was written to log). So I got back to java-ee 6 version 3.0.3.Final and CDI 1.0.

I'm guessing that maybe I cannot find the Interceptor because the path in beans.xml is not the correct one in the jar (it is inside \WEB-INF\lib\loggings-1.2.jar\commons\utils\logging\performanceInterceptor).

Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: Add a `beans.xml` to your Project B. If your project is packed as a WAR file, ensure it's within `WEB-INF`. If it's a JAR file, ensure it's within `META-INF`.

Comment: Project B is not a web app that's why it doesn't have a beans.xml. It is a transversal project that provides common features to inumerous projects.

Comment: Cassio is right, beans.xml will mark Project-B for the CDI engine

Comment: If I add a beans.xml to Project B with the interceptor, (/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml because it is a war) and I remove the interceptor in Project A, the deployment error is gone but it still doesn't call the logMethodEntry method. If I keep the interceptor in both beans.xml the error is the same. Am I missing any extra configuration when adding a beans.xml?

Answer (score 3):

Comments below your question are pointing you in a good direction.

Project B should be a so-called `bean archive` - and in Java EE 6 it is achieved by including a `beans.xml` inside such archive (even completely empty content would be enough).

You said:

> Project B is not a web app that's why it doesn't have a beans.xml. It is a transversal project that provides common features to numerous projects

You're a bit wrong - `beans.xml` in your case **still has to exist**. In a JAR archive it should be placed in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder (if you are using maven).

For WAR packaging it should be placed in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`.

---

Also one more thing: you said in the comments two opposite statements:

> Project B is not a web app

and also:

> If I add a beans.xml to Project B (...) (/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml because it **is a war**)

So what is the truth?

Comment: I was mistaking A and B. Project B is not a web app and is a jar. I should probably add a beans.xml to META-INF instead and give it a try.

Comment: I've added beans.xml to Project B declaring LoggingInterceptor (inside /META-INF/). However, the interceptor is not being called even though I can see the beans.xml in the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, where my Interceptor wasn't called for certain annotated methods and it worked for some other.
The problem was that the class (RESTClient.java) that used the Interceptor annotation wasn't injected, but initialized through constructor.
To solve the issue, I did something like this :

```
@Inject
private Provider<RESTClient> restClientProvider;
//..
RESTClient restClient = restClientProvider.get();
restClient.init(
//do whatever the constructor was doing here.
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In your beans.xml add the tag `bean-discovery-mode` as in the example above:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <interceptors>
        <class>YOUR_CLASS__FROM_THE_JAR</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

2) In the jar which contains the interceptor add inside `src/main/resources` a folder called `META-INF` and inside a `beans.xml` file without the `<interceptors>` tag.

That worked for me.

Also, try creating a standalone container(I recommend WELD) in a class with the method `main` and test your interceptor.